# How do I implement different plans with Stripe on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, stripe-payments

I have my subscribe controller like this :-

```
class SubscribeController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_client!

  def new
  end

  def update
    #gets the credit card details submitted in the form
    token    = params[:stripeToken]

    #create a customer
    customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
      card:  token,
      plan:  111,
      email: current_user.email,
    )

    current_client.subscribed = true
    current_client.stripeid   = customer.id
    current_client.plan_id    = 111
    current_client.save

    redirect_to root_path, notice: "Your subscription was set up successfully!"
  end
end
```

Here 111 is my plan Id for basic.

Now, I want to take this for different payment modes say basic and premium. For example, If the user clicks one button, he should be able to pay for basic say 10$, and if he clicks premium he must be able to pay for premium say 20$.

I have my views like this :-

```
#views/subscirbe/new.html.erb
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 panel panel-default form-style">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <h2>Final Signup Step</h2>
                <h4>This is the final step to give you full access to PinAuth Services</h4>  
                <%= render 'form' %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my _form.html.erb as

```
    <%= form_tag subscribe_path(1), method: :put do %>


<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
          data-key="<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>"
          data-description="A month's subscription"
          data-amount="2900"></script><span> $29 per month, cancel at any time.</span>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I used this https://www.payola.io/blog/payola-subscriptions/

Comment: Also, this looks helpful https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hyEsiwc0ys4

Comment: @Abram, I've tried that youtube link before. Thanks. I got it solved by creating different controllers for different payment methods.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by just creating different controllers for different plans.